# how to give text style to a widget and have the same applied for all its descendents in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Let's say I have a custom widget that I accept as a parameter to be used inside my widget , I want to style all the text inside that widget to a specific font colour.

How do I do this ? I don't want to change the theme of the whole app.
I just want to set the style for the text inside that custom widget.

How to give text style to a widget and have the same applied for all its descendants ?

Comment: Do you want it for the whole project or in a specific screen?

Comment: Just wrap that "custom widget" with "Material" widget and assign the property "textstyle". This will be specific to entire custom widget not for others.

Answer (score 9):

**DefaultTextStyle** Could best solution for changing text style for specific widget tree.

```
DefaultTextStyle(
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
        child: Text("data"),
      ),
```